# How can I change the hinted return type of a function depending on the value of a parameter

Tags: python, typing

I have a function where it usually returns an object that it searches for and performs some other actions. It raises an exception if it fails to find a match. Frequently, I don't care if it finds a match or not, but not frequently enough that I'd consider removing the exception entirely. As such, the compromise I've made is to create a parameter `raise_on_failure` which defaults to `True`. If it is `False`, then `None` is returned rather than the reference.

```py
def searchAndOperate(f, raise_on_failure: bool = True) -> Optional[Foo]:
    # Search
    result = ...
    if result is None:
        if raise_on_failure: raise ValueError("No results")
        else: return None
    # Operate
    ...
    # Then return the result
    return result
```

However, this has caused some issues with my type hinting. I want to make it so that if `raise_on_failure` is `True`, the function is guaranteed to return a `Foo`, such that it is only `Optional[Foo]` if `raise_on_failure` is `False`.

How can I do this? Something akin to the following snippet would be the most desirable, but I'm open to other ideas too.

```py
def searchAndOperate(
    f,
    raise_on_failure: bool = True
) -> Foo if raise_on_failure else Optional[Foo]:
    ...
```

Comment: A solution for this would be really useful, especially in a legacy code base where splitting it into two functions is not really an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others already mentioned that it might be better to refactor the function `searchAndOperate` into two separate functions.

Just for completeness however, it's actually possible to create type annotations for the original behaviour by using the [@overload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) decorator:

```
@overload
def searchAndOperate(f, raise_on_failure: Literal[True] = True) -> Foo: ...
@overload
def searchAndOperate(f, raise_on_failure: Literal[False]) -> Optional[Foo]: ...
@overload
def searchAndOperate(f, raise_on_failure: bool = True) -> Optional[Foo]: ...
def searchAndOperate(f, raise_on_failure = True):
    # Search
    result = ...
    if result is None:
        if raise_on_failure: raise ValueError("No results")
        else: return None
    # Operate
    ...
    # Then return the result
    return result
```

Note that there's an overload for each combination plus one generic fallback. For more comprehensive function signatures that overload list can get quite long. A static type checker like mypy now infers the following return types:

```
a = searchAndOperate(f)  # Foo
b = searchAndOperate(f, raise_on_failure=True)  # Foo
c = searchAndOperate(f, raise_on_failure=False)  # Foo | None
d = searchAndOperate(f, raise_on_failure=(10 > 2))  # Foo | None
e = searchAndOperate(f, raise_on_failure=boolarg)  # Foo | None
```

When using no keyword argument or the literal arguments `True` or `False`, the type checker correctly infers one of the two specialised overloads. When passing a boolean expression or variable the type checker can infer the generic overload only (since it cannot know the actual value without running the code).

Comment: This worked great, although I found that for the assignment of `result` the result had to be `Optional[Foo]` and not a literal `None` or `Foo`, which may help anyone else testing to see if this answer matches their needs. Thanks again for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, I do not think that type hints that change depending on a parameter makes sense.

The type hint `Optional[Foo]` already encapsulates everything that `searchAndOperate` is able to return: anyone who calls it knows that it will return either `Foo` or `None`. Trying to "split" the return types based to the value of `raise_on_failure` couples the function's behavior to its implementation. What you should be doing is *refactoring the function itself* so that its behavior is non-ambiguous. The dissatisfaction with your current type hint stems from the fact that `searchAndOperate` tries to do too many things at once.

For example, `searchAndOperate` may be split into single-responsibility functions `search` and `operate`. Or you could just ditch the `raise_on_failure` parameter entirely, and leave to the caller to try/except the function call. If it becomes something you do a lot, you could wrap it as a separate function, something like:

```
def searchAndOperate(f) -> Foo:
    """Searches and returns Foo. Raises a ValueError if no result is found."""
    result = ...
    if result is None:
        raise ValueError("No result")
    return result

def trySearchAndOperate(f) -> Optional[Foo]:
    """Searches and returns Foo. Returns None if no result is found."""
    try:
        result = searchAndOperate(f)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

This way, the caller already knows what to expect when no results are found. You might think that this is somewhat repetitive, but it is a common pattern: the only difference between `'abc'.index(s)` and `'abc'.find(s)` is that the first raises an exception if `s` isn't found in `'abc'`, and the second returns a default value of `-1` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I was mainly wrapping the parameter up into the one function as there's already a few variants of the function which have similar (but different) behaviour, and I wanted to avoid having to double the number of functions available in the object.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is possible.

The return type hint is supposed to tell you, *without looking at the values of the arguments*, what the function returns.

You are essentially implementing two different behaviors in this function:

1. Return a `Foo` or crash
2. Return a `Foo` or `None`

If you want to encode this in a type hint, you have to consider both cases. That means that the function *is* `Optional[Foo]`.

If you want it not to be, I would suggest splitting this function into two different functions; one that raises and one that does dot:

```py
def search_and_operate(f) -> Optional[Foo]:
    result = ... # some code that either results in a Foo object or None
    return result

def search_and_operate_or_raise(f) -> Foo:
    result = search_and_operate(f)
    if result is None:
        raise ValueError("No result")
    return result
```